# jQuery accordion - selecting child element

Tags: jquery, accordion

Im trying to build a simple accordion that meets certain accessibility standards -hence needing it replace the button element so that I can have different accessibility text for open and closed states.

It works if there is just one on the page but with there are multiple it opens and closes all of them. I know why this is and I know I need to do something like select the child element of the button instead but I'm not sure how to write it (still learning jQuery).

So my question is, how do I change the script so it selects the div under the clicked button only

```js
$(function() {
 'use strict';
 $(".openAccord").click(function() {
  $(".accordion-text").slideDown("slow");
  $(".openAccord").hide();
  $(".closeAccord").show();
 });
});

$(function() {
 'use strict';
 $(".closeAccord").click(function() {
  $(".accordion-text").slideUp("slow");
  $(".closeAccord").hide();
  $(".openAccord").show();
 });
});
```

```css
.accord button {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

button.closeAccord {
 display: none;
 background-color: #fec445;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.accord h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 
}

.accordion-text {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 18px;
 background-color: #efefef;
}

h4.open {
 background-image:url(../images/dropdown.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}

h4.close {
 background-image:url(../images/dropup.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

instead of all the divs?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(".openAccord").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".accordion-text").slideDown("slow");
    $(".openAccord").hide();
    $(".closeAccord").show();
  });
});

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(".closeAccord").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".accordion-text").slideUp("slow");
    $(".closeAccord").hide();
    $(".openAccord").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.accord button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
button.closeAccord {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fec445;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.accord h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.accordion-text {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
h4.open {
  background-image: url(../images/dropdown.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
h4.close {
  background-image: url(../images/dropup.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord">
  <button class="openAccord">
    <h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <button class="closeAccord">
    <h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
  <button class="openAccord">
    <h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <button class="closeAccord">
    <h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
  <button class="openAccord">
    <h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <button class="closeAccord">
    <h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4>
  </button>
  <div class="accordion-text">
    <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Use siblings to find the text.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
 'use strict';
 $(".openAccord").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".accordion-text").slideDown("slow");
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).siblings(".closeAccord").show();
 });
});

$(function() {
 'use strict';
 $(".closeAccord").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".accordion-text").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings(".openAccord").show();
 });
});
```

```css
.accord button {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

button.closeAccord {
 display: none;
 background-color: #fec445;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.accord h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 
}

.accordion-text {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 18px;
 background-color: #efefef;
}

h4.open {
 background-image:url(../images/dropdown.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}

h4.close {
 background-image:url(../images/dropup.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One function is enough. Not necessary to add function for each event.

No need to add `openAccord` and `closeAccord` classes inside click function instear of classes add `this` refers to the clicked element. Use siblings to find inside elements.

```js
$(function() {

 $(".openAccord").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.accordion-text').slideDown("slow");
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find(".closeAccord").show();
 });

 $(".closeAccord").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".accordion-text").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().find(".openAccord").show();
 });
});
```

```css
.accord button {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

button.closeAccord {
 display: none;
 background-color: #fec445;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.accord h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 
}

.accordion-text {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 18px;
 background-color: #efefef;
}

h4.open {
 background-image:url(../images/dropdown.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}

h4.close {
 background-image:url(../images/dropup.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord"><h4 class="close">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function() {
      'use strict';

      $(".openAccord").click(function() {
        var $accordion = $(this).closest('.accord');
        $accordion.find(".accordion-text").slideDown("slow");
        $accordion.find(".openAccord").hide();
        $accordion.find(".closeAccord").show();
      });

      $(".closeAccord").click(function() {
        var $accordion = $(this).closest('.accord');
        $accordion.find(".accordion-text").slideUp("slow");
        $accordion.find(".closeAccord").hide();
        $accordion.find(".openAccord").show();
      });
    });
```

```css
.accord button {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

button.closeAccord {
 display: none;
 background-color: #fec445;
 border: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

.accord h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 18px;
 margin: 0;
 
}

.accordion-text {
 display: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 18px;
 background-color: #efefef;
}

h4.open {
 background-image:url(../images/dropdown.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}

h4.close {
 background-image:url(../images/dropup.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord">Close accord</button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord">Close accord</button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="accord">
 <button class="openAccord"><h4 class="open">This is the accordion heading</h4></button>
 <button class="closeAccord">Close accord</button>
 <div class="accordion-text">
  <p>This is the text in the accordion</p>
 </div>
</div>
```